# search for portion of a string in a field name in matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I am trying to find a way to see if a string is included in a field name.

```
fieldName = 'OneTwoThree';
```

I want

`findTwo` == true if `fieldName` contains char `'Two'` somewhere in string

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`fieldnames`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html) and then [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html).

```
a.OneTwoThree = 4; %// first field name
a.AnotherField = 'hello'; %// second example field name
```

To test all field names:

```
names = fieldnames(a); %// gives all field names
findTwo = ~isempty(strfind(names,'Two'));
```

To test only first field:

```
names = fieldnames(a); %// gives all field names
findTwo = ~isempty(strfind(names{1},'Two'));
```